# How to get JSON data from custom end point of WP Rest Api and apply it to Gutenberg custom block component

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I want to get JSON object from custom end point that I made and apply it as options for 
React Select component.

Registration of my custom end point

```
register_rest_route('namespace/v1', 'products', array(
    'methods'  => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
    'callback' => 'namespace_result_products',
));
```

JSON object that web browser showing is below.
I think it's fine.

```
[
  {
    "value": 15,
    "label": "Apple"
  },
  {
    "value": 21,
    "label": "Banana"
  },
  {
    "value": 18,
    "label": "Apple"
  },...
```

Edit function of my gutenberg custom block.

```
edit: props => {
const { attributes: { selectedOption }, setAttributes } = props;
const handleSelectChange = ( selectedOption ) => setAttributes( { selectedOption: JSON.stringify( selectedOption ) } );
return (
    <InspectorControls>
        <PanelBody
            title={ 'Products'}
        >
            <PanelRow>
                <Select
                    name='select'
                    value={ JSON.parse( selectedOption ) }
                    onChange={ handleSelectChange }
                    options={[
                        // !!!!!!!!  I want to apply my JSON data here  !!!!!!!! 
                    ]}
                    isMulti='true'
                    />
            </PanelRow>
        </PanelBody>
    </InspectorControls>
    )
},
```

By hard coding, this works fine.

```
<PanelRow>
    <Select
        name='select'
        value={ JSON.parse( selectedOption ) }
        onChange={ handleSelectChange }
        options={[
            { value: '15', label: 'Apple' },
            { value: '21', label: 'Banana' },
            { value: '18', label: 'Apple' },
        ]}
        isMulti='true'
        />
</PanelRow>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your component make an Ajax call in the componentDidMount lifecycle method and set the state. Like this.

```
fetch('http://url.com/namespace/v1/products')
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({
          options: data
    });
```

This will set the state of your component to have your json from your endpoint inside a property called options.

Then in you return where you hardcoded your data call the state.

```
<PanelRow>
    <Select
        name='select'
        value={ JSON.parse( selectedOption ) }
        onChange={ handleSelectChange }
        options={this.state.options}
        isMulti='true'
    />
</PanelRow>
```

This will throw an error if it tries to mount the component before the state is set so make sure to wrap you return statement in a check.

```
if(this.state.options) {
    return(...) //your components return
} else {
    return <p>Loading</p>
}
```